# how can I detect eye corner in eye image using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to estimate gaze direction. at the first step I've extracted the iris location. at the second step I have to detect eye corners. I've tried this code:

```
I=one_eye;;
h=fspecial('gaussian',[5 10],100);
I=imfilter(I,h);
h = fspecial('sobel');
I=imfilter(I,h);
% h=fspecial('gaussian',[1000 500],10);
% I=imfilter(I,h);

cornerDetector = vision.CornerDetector( ... 
             'Method', 'Local intensity comparison (Rosten & Drummond)');
pts = step(cornerDetector, I);
color = [1 0 0];
J = insertMarker(one_eye, pts, 'Color', 'red');
figure, imshow(J); title ('Corners detected in a grayscale image');

imwrite(J,'corners.jpg');
```

but many points are detected as corner. I don't know what's wrong with it?!

Comment: Could you upload an example image?

Comment: Did you expect a corner detector to pick the corner of the eye *only*? There's probably nothing "wrong" as such, your expectations are just too high.

Comment: What is an "eye corner"?

Comment: I can't upload any images. it has an error. it says : you need at least 10 reputation to post images. I don't know what does it means.

Comment: perhaps my expectation is just too high but what's the solution? I need coordinates of eye corners (eye canthus)

Comment: @HediehHeli If you upload the image somewhere else and provide a link, then somebody with more reputation can insert the image for you.

Comment: @hbaderts I'll do it if I can. thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

Corner detection methods try to find the points on edges which satisfy some criteria. So, if your images consist of just squares or rectangles, your corner detector would work perfectly.

However, there are of course some problems:

1 - Your image is noisy.

2 - Gradient calculations are highly affected by noise.

3 - I don't know your method, but Corner detectors also use gradients, so they are also prone to noise.

4 - Furthermore, you use Sobel which is also a gradient operator.

So, it is quite normal that you get lots of false positives. As @nkjt said, your expectations are too high.

Take a look at the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection) to get an idea about corner detection.